# Installing Mongo Driver on AWS ami (php 5.6.9)

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, php-extension

Command:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

[image]

I am not sure why I get the missing phpize.m4 error and why I'm getting all these 'stat' errors. I've added the same version of php (5.6.9) to the /usr/lib64/php/5.6/ folder and ran ./configure which executes with no errors.

```
pear version
```

[image]

Comment: ** UPDATE ** I had php-devel installed and I needed php56-devel. I'm still not done installing the driver but I am one step closer. Latest error now is... ERROR: `/var/tmp/mongo/configure --with-mongo-sasl=n' failed

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/466345/mongo-driver-php-cant-install-sasl-h-not-found This article helped me. I had to run yum install cyrus-sasl-devel

Answer (score 0):

I had a few dependencies that were not properly installed.

Instead of php-devel I needed php56-devel for my specific version.

```
yum install php56-devel

yum install cyrus-sasl-devel (missing dependency once I ran the pecl install again)
```